# How to define an object of type of another type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

I'm working on a Rest API using express and typescript. I have controller classes whose functions serve as router handlers. During the execution of these functions I can raise custom exceptions when business rules aren't fulfilled e.g. "Item not found" or "Item already exists". I've done it using the following design:

```
//BaseController.ts
interface ErrorMap {
    type: any;
    code: number;
}

export default interface BaseController {
    errorMappings: ErrorMap[]; //allows custom error registration in controllers
}

//CustomError.ts
export default class SampleExistsError extends Error {
    //implementation details...
}

//Custom controller
export default class SampleController implements BaseController {

    async addSampleHandler(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        //code that can throw a SampleExistsError...
    }

    errorMappings = [
        //as you see, I want to register the type
        { type: SampleExistsError, code: 400 }
        //there may be other error types registered here here...
    ];
}

//Custom routerErrorMiddleware
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
function routerErrorMiddleware(controller: BaseController) {
    return (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        let handled = false;
        for (const errorMapping of controller.errorMappings) {
            if (err instanceof errorMapping.type) {
                const result = {
                    message: err.message
                };
                handled = true;
                //line below commented because it's not necessary to reproduce the warning/errors
                //res.status(errorMapping.code).json(result);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!handled) {
            console.log("Error type not found. Looking for next error middleware.");
            next(err);
        }
    };
}
```

So far so good, the design works as expected. But then I get a warning from the linter here:

```
interface ErrorMap {
    type: any //<--- Here's my problem
    code: number
}
```

I tried changing the definition with these options

```
//Option 1
interface ErrorMap {
    type: Error; //this breaks the assignment in CustomController
    code: number;
}

//Option 2
interface ErrorMap<T extends Error> {
    type: T; //this breaks the definition in BaseController
    code: number;
}

//Option 3
interface ErrorMap<T extends Error> {
    type: { new(): T }; //same as option 2
    code: number;
}
```

What can I use instead of `any` for the `type` definition?

Added a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=false&jsx=0&module=7&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=false&pretty=true&ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgOQKYA8YDECuA7AYxmAjwBo4AlVARx1QGcYLqHI8HU4BfOAMygQQcAEQYwURgxEBuAFBzgeGKih8AhgS4BRKIKgBZdWERy45uAHpLAGSUqocABaquUdcE4M46uAHV1KDwlAHMzC2sRAFU8cVQiVAATHzwATwA6OABlMHjgPlSfOET8vldlOBhU3MzGABt7AAoAASrchgIoYDAYAFp6+0s8CH70MAaCYD71NIBKEXDzNtQALhTU+Qs4AghE1bg8HBAAI1V5bgV7VQ0tOAAhdU4AYVIYQTq61VMt1X0jMDAoQYa10f2MAG0ALoyKyWdQfCAAd28BBwTCEcF+0DgkhCnje6mIpDgSm2r3enygDDkFzk1ieaJgQlB0HSMGpBDqj28WXU4E+2nQ+IYLMcGBUeES3lF3willA41QIFQykJJDwxVQMA8dQY6X1NIU9MZGJ2ygpqjknO52T5ipe5ogHy+Cs+yuU3gez3JTsppkWPgYqUIPkSiV5-NQAAkZolKY1JDQ1tQ6IxmDjGMnGOxOLM1gAFQQgTyoAA8ADcIMBEgA+WVbczWHZ7SpOQnbGatwSIooRxWC4Wi-XpAO0n56aD-QF4ELeAC8cHBAa21kecFSEBwcE4qAoAEk4IiZvAmRm8UwvjAXJVqqhlxYkMs1n2BUKmCKJ1AKM39gAWAAM-48PejaWFerhwCA6iFKccAQOBYqfje7RnvirjJC4kjOK4w4BtChpyHw+BEOqOKbg4ooGNWcaoEekiNGaby+qoaxeqgDpMc6UCzPWGYwDgQRwI0vwgp+FCJlmqZMOJmZUNmpCcBQsSYGsaCYLghBEngPFznWCAgXAnzwG2kqfMkC4aLqqCbA25h8NiDEKfAWKGMY04hHBfBko6XHpC5U5Ajx+m2bZ+RCb8JIcNqhCoBAXn+W5oRsreQUGSF3lMBmDA4HU8ALsF6WFeYyoMAw6ghPsvzpCVZUVWlIXcDZRVbCZNHmZUUD0E1zWgTsIDuioySnAQ6holw4FwOM0EhII+DJIkECMHgADk8CSDsITBAAXuN15EZp6reMSAAGkgMMd9W2dYZ3pEwhJosJn4BTO6Q-rM6QAFYMKQCaMDlMCzN1PXHJI6gANZAw1BkXOlYWNAAhK1ZmpT1ZrfZ86R1BAISNCIMrLAc8H8JukqZDYEAQGDoTE44ynOUhxZhp8dGoOkIiA5dBzio93GQ+YMMWI1hpAA) to replicate the warning (it doesn't show in the playground because I cannot define the linter rule here).

Comment: Apologies if I'm just missing it, but what error is the linter giving you on the `type: any` line?

Comment: Could you [edit] the code in the question so it's a [mre] others can copy and paste into their own IDEs and demonstrate the issue?  There shouldn't be undefined/unneeded types (what's `SampleExistsError`? what's `NextFunction`? are you using the same `Response` type built in to TypeScript? If so, why are you calling `status` like a method when it's a `number`?).  The only issue present should be the one you're asking about (including any module or multi-file nature; have it be one file unless your question is *about* modules)

Comment: @WadeJ it doesn't give me an error, just a warning

Comment: @jcalz those types come from express. I edited the question to add the import. And `SampleExistsError` is a custom error I created, as stated in the code.

Comment: Please either define `SampleExistsError` or remove it, to make it more straightforward for others to work on.  Also could you tag your question as depending on express, assuming that it does? If it doesn't then I'd suggest removing the dependency to get a nice [mre] that doesn't require people looking up 3rd party type definitions.

Comment: Also, your updated code seems to have an error `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'.`.  Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: But what is the warning? We need to know exactly what is going on to be of the most help.

I'm assuming the linter is giving a warning that `any` should just be avoided in general. Is that correct?

Like @jcalz mentioned, a minimal reproducible example would be very helpful. You can use the TypeScript Playground to provide a really handy link for everyone: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play
It's appreciated that you mentioned what you tried! But they have the same problem where they say "this breaks..." instead of saying _how_ they break.

Comment: @jcalz added the playground

Comment: So does `Function` work for you instead of `any` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJApgm)?  That allows an `instanceof` to go through; not sure what else you need though.

Answer (score 0):

`unknown` can usually be used instead

Comment: This raises an error in `routerErrorMiddleware`, when checking the type: `if (err instanceof errorMapping.type)`

Answer (score 0):

You can take is to use a union of specific error types instead of the any type. This pwould allow the compiler to catch errors when you are trying to use an incorrect error type. For example:

```
interface ErrorMap {
  type: SampleExistsError | ItemNotFoundError;
  code: number;
}
```